# Drive partitioning slow in SSD than HDD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, diskpart

Partitioning my SSD is very slow compared to that in my other PC which is having an HDD. Why is that?
I believe it shouldn't be. I could shrink a volume in just max 5 seconds in my HDD PC and it takes forever in my SSD PC. Is it the SSD? Or does my computer have any problem? Or the problem is with me?
Someone please clarify.

Comment: The time required for shrinking a partition depends on the number of blocks that have to me moved away for being able to shrink the partition. In the end it is just coincidence where blocks are written and therefore shrinking an HDD partition can be fast (because no blocks have to be moved) where as an SSD shrinking can take some time if several GB of data blocks have to be moved.

Answer (score 3):

SSD's are NAND based, and need a lot of empty "blocks" to operate at the higher ssd speed. HDD's overwrite data easily, but SSD's can only delete and add blocks. If your SSD isn't wiped during formatting (which takes a while), the SSD will be slow for a very long time.

Hardware.info (Dutch only, but you can use google translate) has a nice article about this subject: https://be.hardware.info/artikel/9973/hoe-werkt-een-ssd

Conclusion: It's the ssd, but it's with all ssd's

Comment: What do you mean by 'slow for a very long time'? Till I format?
What if I haven't formatted my SSD in a while? Will it slow down my whole PC?

Comment: noo, then you need to trim to delete "empty" blocks. Could take a while and maybe needs to be done multiple times. But some filesystems trim part of the ssd when you delete a file, so that should be no issue

Comment: and that "slow for a very long time" is until you rewrote every block and then made room for your files. Normally this will empty the blocks full of old data